# MySQL 8.0+ REGEXP_REPLACE equivalent function for older version of the MySQL <= 5.7

Tags: mysql

I need to correct an invalid date column in the MYSQL database. I have written a following query for the fix, which works fine in MySQL 8.0+, however my database server only runs MySQL 5.7

I would like to know is there equalant function or how can i do the same thing in MYSQL 5.7 ?

```
UPDATE `file` 

SET date_complete = REGEXP_REPLACE(date_complete, "([[:digit:]]{2})-([[:digit:]]{2})-([[:digit:]]{4})", '\\3-\\2-\\1')

WHERE date_complete REGEXP "([[:digit:]]{2})-([[:digit:]]{2})-([[:digit:]]{4})"
AND date_complete IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: MySQL proir to 8.0 have no regular expression support except pattern matching testing. Use external REGEX module (.so) with according user-defined function.

Comment: PS. If `.. WHERE date_complete REGEXP ..` is TRUE then `.. AND date_complete IS NOT NULL` is obviously TRUE. Hence the last condition is excess and must be removed. PPS. Do **NOT** use double-quote chars as string quote chars, use single quotes.

Comment: After changing the data if you are using mysql workbench you could use the table export & import wizard to export that data from the table in mysql 8(as a csv or json file) and reimport it in mysql 5.7